# Using rename and grep patterns to rename files in Terminal

Tags: regex, rename

I am trying to change the name of a number of files in a directory using `rename`, but the pattern that I'm using is not working with `rename`, even though it works in my text editor (BBEdit). I would like to know how to modify the `rename` command I'm using or the pattern so that I can get rid of the long prefix that each file has.

My directory listing looks like this:

```
bos012_attempt_2018-02-15-01-52-18_KIC Document 0001.pdf
gem512_attempt_2018-02-14-20-30-11_Geo HW 2.pdf
kgs252_attempt_2018-02-14-23-35-03_kgs252_hw2.pdf
nrs728_attempt_2018-02-15-10-04-42_mids.png
oko018_attempt_2018-02-15-23-57-57_Hw2.pdf
```

I want to change this to

```
KIC Document 0001.pdf
Geo HW 2.pdf
kgs252_hw2.pdf
mids.png
Hw2.pdf
```

Using `rename -vs 's/\D\D\D\d\d\d_attempt_2018-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d_/''/g' *`
produces no changes in the names. Nevertheless, changing the pattern `\D\D\D\d\d\d_attempt_2018-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d_` to no character works just fine in my text editor. I've tried different things, e.g.

`rename -vs \D\D\D\d\d\d_attempt_2018-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d_ '' *`

and nothing.

`mydir $ rename -nvs \D\D\D\d\d\d_attempt_2018-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d-\d\d_ '' *`

returns

```
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18';
s/\Q${\"DDDddd_attempt_2018\-dd\-dd\-dd\-dd\-dd_"}// }
'bos012_attempt_2018-02-15-01-52-18_KIC_Document_0001.pdf' unchanged
'gem512_attempt_2018-02-14-20-30-11_Geo_HW_2.pdf' unchanged
'nrs728_attempt_2018-02-15-10-04-42_mids.png' unchanged
'oko018_attempt_2018-02-15-23-57-57_Hw2.pdf' unchanged
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of `rename`, you may use this `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/.*_attempt_\d{4}(-\d{2}){5}_//' *.{pdf,png}
```

```
'bos012_attempt_2018-02-15-01-52-18_KIC Document 0001.pdf' would be renamed to 'KIC Document 0001.pdf'
'gem512_attempt_2018-02-14-20-30-11_Geo HW 2.pdf' would be renamed to 'Geo HW 2.pdf'
'kgs252_attempt_2018-02-14-23-35-03_kgs252_hw2.pdf' would be renamed to 'kgs252_hw2.pdf'
'oko018_attempt_2018-02-15-23-57-57_Hw2.pdf' would be renamed to 'Hw2.pdf'
'nrs728_attempt_2018-02-15-10-04-42_mids.png' would be renamed to 'mids.png'
```

If you are satisfied with the output remove `-n` argument of dry-run.

Comment: did not work for me. returned without any message. using `-n` or without `-n`.

Comment: Your filenames might be using different pattern or you might not be using same `rename` perl utility.

Comment: I just realized that `rename` has no recursive option. That was the problem. But I wish it had.

Comment: Use it `find ... -exec`

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling. Its `-regex` is not acting as I expect. Thank you for your help.